# How can get chat history of users in botpress?

Tags: node.js, chat, node-modules, history, botpress

I am working on Botpress chatbot. I need to send an email with a current user chat history. I have no idea how to achieve this. 
Version using: Botpress V12.2.0

I googled and documents. but found nothing related to it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to query the database with the current userId. The table in your version may vary. In current version the table in postgresql is msg_messages where you have a field with the actual payload of the conversations. You will need to use json operators of psql to extract the text of the conversation to email it.